# Waiting for an event with message pump on compactframework

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I used to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects with success to wait on the event's handle and pump messages at the same time.

However I don't have that procedure on Windows Mobile.

The situation is as follows:

- I open form which displays some animation
- Run thread
- Wait until thread finishes (when it sets event to Set())

Without pumping messages I will not see the animation on the form as waiting for the thread using WaitOne for instance, is blocking everything ...

How can I achieve the same functionality on Windows Mobile?

Thanks

Comment: For what it is worth, you can alos p/invoke MsgWaitForMultipleObjects on the CE platform.  Works fine, very useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to achieve what you're looking for is to use the BackgroundWorker class that's part of the [OpenNETCF framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx)

It's essentially a functional copy of the System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker class from the full .NET framework.

Execute as follows:

1. start animation on form load event
2. start backgroundworker
3. wait for backgroundworker to fire completion event.

Below is an example adapted from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) backgroundworker class documentation that may point you in the right direction.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();

    }

    // Set up the BackgroundWorker object by  
    // attaching event handlers.  
    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += 
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += 
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += 
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
        backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {

        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            // start your animation here!


            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }



    // This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

         //this is taken from the msdn example, but you would fill 
         //it in with whatever code is being executed on your bg thread.
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //modify your animation here if you like?
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your background process is done. tear down your form here..


    }
```

Comment: But how exactly wait for completion? What would that backgroundworker do for me? I just don't get the idea ...